# How to install Adobe Flash Player for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, flash

It is out of date right now but I need it for an urgent business. It was installed in my computer but after January 11 it suddenly stopped to work. I know Flash Player is expired but there is no other way for me to access old newspaper issues as a student doing research

Comment: https://alternativeto.net/software/flash-player/?platform=linux and https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1279616

Comment: which release? `apt search flashplugin-installer `

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alternative `gnash` available for Ubuntu Xenial and Bionic:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt install gnash browser-plugin-gnash
```

Description of [`browser-plugin-gnash`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/browser-plugin-gnash):

> GNU Shockwave Flash (SWF) player - Plugin for Mozilla and derivatives

Comment: What about focal fossa?